# How to set a default value to a dropdown list based on the specific value of another dropdown list (if empty) in dash?

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have a dash with 8 drop down lists, they work by pair meaning that for a drop-down list I can select ['EUR','USD','GBP', ''] and the associated drop-down list displays the value associated with the currency I mentioned.
Example: if I select 'EUR' in the first dropdown list, I will be offered some options (eur_ticker) in the associated dropdown list.

But, in the case I select '' in the first dropdown list, I want to the second dropdown list not to display any options but that its value is automatically set as [''].
(For the moment, I am proposing with only option [''] and I need to select it which is not user friendly).

Here is part of my code.
Does multiple outputs work in dash? How to work with it?

```
ccy_bond['EUR'] = eur_ticker
ccy_bond['USD'] = usd_ticker
ccy_bond['GBP'] = gbp_ticker
ccy_bond[''] = ['']


                       dbc.Col(['TRADE 1',
                             dbc.Col('Pay'),
                             dbc.Row([
                                 dbc.Col([
                                     dcc.Dropdown(
                                         id='dd-ccy-1s-id',
                                         options=[
                                             {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ccy
                                         ],
                                         value='EUR',
                                         clearable=False,
                                     ),
                                 ], xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=3, xl=3),

                                 dbc.Col([
                                     dcc.Dropdown(
                                         id='dd-bond-1s-id',
                                         options=[
                                             {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in eur_ticker
                                         ],
                                         value=eur_ticker[4],
                                         clearable=False,
                                     )
                                 ], xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=9, xl=9),
                             ]),
                             dbc.Col('Receive'),
                             dbc.Row([
                                 dbc.Col([
                                     dcc.Dropdown(
                                         id='dd-ccy-1b-id',
                                         options=[
                                             {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ccy
                                         ],
                                         value='EUR',
                                         clearable=False,
                                     ),
                                 ], xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=3, xl=3),
                                 dbc.Col([
                                     dcc.Dropdown(
                                         id='dd-bond-1b-id',
                                         options=[
                                             {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in eur_ticker
                                         ],
                                         value=eur_ticker[9],
                                         clearable=False,
                                     )
                                 ], xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=9, xl=9),
                             ]),

                             dbc.Col(id="graph1-trade1-id"),
                             dbc.Col(id="graph2-trade1-id")

                             ], xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=4, xl=4),

 # trade 1 - pay
 @app.callback(
 [
    Output("dd-bond-1s-id", "options"),

 ],
 [
    Input("dd-ccy-1s-id", "value"),
 ]
 )
def dd_update(ccy):
      res = [
          {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ccy_bond[ccy]
            ],
      return res


# trade 1 - receive
@app.callback(
[
  Output("dd-bond-1b-id", "options"),

],
[
  Input("dd-ccy-1b-id", "value"),
]
)
def dd_update2(ccy):
res = [
          {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ccy_bond[ccy]
      ],
return res
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are allowed to have multiple outputs in the same callback. So you could set `options` and `value` at the same time, such as in:

```py
 @app.callback(
 [
    Output("dd-bond-1s-id", "options"),
    Output("dd-bond-1s-id", "value"),
 ],
 [
    Input("dd-ccy-1s-id", "value"),
 ]
 )
def dd_update(ccy):
      res = [
          {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ccy_bond[ccy]
            ]
      value = res[0]["value"] # For simplicity
      
      return res, value
```

As for the empty selection "", I would add a third output with the property "disabled" and return `True` if the selection is made. This way you prevent people from selecting other values.